# What is the best way to know if the configuration changed?

Tags: android, android-configchanges

I am not sure how to get this information on my apps: how to know when an activity has been restarted because of a configuration change? (any configuration change).

In my code I need to execute a method if the activity restarted "normally" but not because of a configuration change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an `Activity` is being restarted due to configuration changes, it is guaranteed that `onDestroy()` method will be called.  In `onDestroy()` method, you can use [isChangingConfigurations()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isChangingConfigurations%28%29), to check whether `Activity` is being destroyed  inorder to be recreated due to configuration changes. Since Activity state cannot be saved as `onSaveInstanceState()` will be called before `onStop()` method, you think of using `SharedPreference` to save the state and latter retrieve it in `onCreate()` method.

By handling this in `onDestroy()` method, we ensure that we handle a case of background Activity which was previously started say in Portrait mode, now trying to be displayed in Landscape mode.

Comment: It seems to be indeed the most appropriate way, too bad this cannot be saved in the instance state as you said.

Answer (score 3):

When the `onConfigurationChanged()` method to detect the Orientation changes.

Class level variable

```
private boolean isOrientationChanged = false;
```

Assign true value when orientation gets changed

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    isOrientationChanged = true;
}
```

Check value in onRestart() method and reset it

```
@Override 
public void onRestart() 
{
    if ( isOrientationChanged ) 
    {
          isOrientationChanged = false;         // reset the  variable for future action.
          // Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I thought about that, but it implies that I change my manifest to add all the possible configurations in the tag `android:configChanges`. If it is the only way I will do it but I thought there would be maybe something more simple.

Comment: @YoannHercouet, hmm lets see what other users provide the solution.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it is a solution, but I leave it open in case someone provides one more straightforward

Comment: @YoannHercouet, ok, even I too want to see what is better/best solution for this requirement. May be I will need it in my next application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OnConfigurationChange method for checking the current config.

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

```
if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
{

}
else if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
{

}
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```